# Some assumptions in linear regression models

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, nonlinear-regression

If I have a vector y which follows a multivariate normal distribution with **zero mean** and unknown covariance matrix. I have the following simple linear regression:
$y = \beta_0 + X\beta_1 + e$.

If I consider now that the vector y follows a multivariate normal distribution with **non zero mean** (and unknown) and unknown covariance matrix. So what can differ in the formula of the simple linear regression??

So by assuming that the mean vector of y is unknown, what can this affect the estimation of the regression coefficients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normality assumption in OLS is on the error term, not the dependent variable.  A non zero mean on the error term could simply be added to $\beta$ and subtracted from the error term, meaning that any model with nonzero mean is equivalent to a model with zero mean.  Therefore it is reasonable to always assume this error has zero mean.

**edit for detail:**

Consider model 1:

$X$ and $E$ are random variables. $E$ is normal with mean $\mu$.  Define the random variable

$$
Y = a + bX + E.
$$

Now define $c = a + \mu$ and $D = E - \mu$. Notice that

$$
Y = c + bX + D.
$$

So any relationship between $X, Y$ that can be described by a linear model with Gaussian noise, can be described by a linear model with Gaussian noise of mean zero.

Comment: Why you didn't also add $\mu$ to $b$?

Comment: Why would I?  b is being multiplied by X.  We are trying to add and subtract a constant from the RHS of the equation, to preserve equality with Y.

Comment: ah so if we assume that a is equal to zero, so we will have $Y = \mu + bX + D$. Thank you anyway :)